# What are some ways to tell that $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| x = y^2 \}$ is a closed set?

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Given a set of the form $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2| x = y^2 \}$

What are some ways to tell that it is a closed set?

So the approach I am using is that this set is closed if its complement is open. I can draw this curve on a 2D grid, which looks something like $\subset$ and then take its complement. For any point in this complement, I can squeeze in a ball so that it is in the complement. This means the complement is open. Hence this set is closed.

I am not very satisfied because this argument is graphical and a bit handwavy.

I also tried to use the sequential definition for showing closedness, i.e., any sequence that is contained in this set will have a limit in it. But again, a bit on the graphical side.

Are there any other approach?

Comment: First, you should point out in which topology are you working? I suppose you are working with the Euclidean metric.

Now, since closed sets are defined using open sets, the most natural way to prove your claim is by your mentioned idea, just that you need to do some technical work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The map $f(x, y) = x - y^2$ is continuous. $\{0\}$ is a closed set. Therefore, $f^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{(x, y) \mid x = y^2\}$ is closed.

This follows from the general fact that if $f : A \to B$ is continuous and $C \subseteq B$ is closed then $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed.

Comment: This is by far the easiest, to exploit continuity.  A more annoying way is to show that for any point where $x\neq y^2$,  there's a small enough disk around that point where for every point in that disk $x\neq y^2$

Comment: @Alan Using sequences is another easy way. If $(x_n, y_n)$ is a sequence of points in this set which converges to $(x,y)$ then it easily follows that $x=y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $Γ:=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2|x=y^2\}$ is the graph of real function $f(x)=\pm \sqrt x, x\in \Bbb R_0^+$, so it can be presented as the orbit of the parametrized curve $γ(t)=(t,\pm \sqrt t), t\geq 0$. Let $x\in Γ^c$; for $\epsilon:=\frac {d(x,Γ)}{2}>0$ the open disc $D(x;\epsilon)$ has no intersection with $Γ$, so $D(x;\epsilon)\subset Γ^c$, namely $Γ^c$ is an open set. Consequently $Γ$ is a closed set.